# uitableview checkbox reset issue

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have my uitableview with 20 rows which is showing a number of food items.

Each food item is having a check box along with it.

My problem is: If I check the first row of the check box and then scroll the tableview, the checkmark is reset.

How can I solve this problem? Please help me out.

Code update:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
  if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
  {
    UIButton *checkboxButton = (UIButton*)sender;

    checkboxButton.selected = !checkboxButton.selected;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell*)[[checkboxButton superview] superview]];

    BOOL selected = [[selectedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] boolValue];

    [selectedArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row] withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!selected]];

      if (!self.checkedIndexPaths)
          checkedIndexPaths = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

    if(selected == NO)
    {
          NSLog(@"cvbcvbNO BOOL value");    // ...

        //  If we are checking this cell, we do
        [self.checkedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
      NSLog(@"cvbvbYES BOOL VALURE");

        //  If we are checking this cell, we do
        [self.checkedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
    }



  }
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Celhgl";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  profileName = [appDelegate.sentItemsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  if (cell == nil)
  {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cb = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,10, unselectedImage.size.width, unselectedImage.size.height)];
        [cb setImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cb setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [cb addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cb];

        for (NSIndexPath *path in self.checkedIndexPaths)
        {
            NSLog(@"%d",path.row);

            NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);

           if (path.row == indexPath.row)
          {
            NSLog(@"dfd %d",indexPath.row);
          }
        }

   }

    if ( tableView == myTableView )
    {
        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0, 150, 35)];
        titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
        titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];   
        [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];
        NSString *subjectData = [profileName.sent_subject stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        [titleLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ ", subjectData]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening is that UITableView is recycling UITableViewCells to save memory. This means that as you scroll down the list the UITableView is taking cells off the top of the table and reusing them to display later items so when you scroll back up they have lost state.

You could rectify this by keeping an `NSMutableSet` of checked indexPaths. When the user checks an item, you would add its `indexPath` to this set. Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can make sure to check the item if it's in your set of checked items.

**UPDATE**

Here's a rough example of how this might work:

```
# MyTableView.h

@interface MyTableView: UITableView
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
  NSMutableSet *checkedIndexPaths;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableSet *checkedIndexPaths;

@end
```

then

```
# MyTableView.m
#import "MyTableView.h"

@implementation MyTableView

@synthesize checkedIndexPaths;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  //  Normal layout stuff goes here...
  //  ***Add code to make sure the checkbox in this cell is unticked.***

  for (NSIndexPath *path in self.checkedIndexPaths)
  {
    if (path.section == indexPath.section && path.row == indexPath.row)
    {
      //  ***We found a matching index path in our set of checked index paths, so we need to show this to the user by putting a tick in the check box, for instance***
    }
  }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  //  Normal stuff to handle visual checking/unchecking of row here

  //  Lazy-load the mutable set
  if (!self.checkedIndexPaths)
    checkedIndexPaths = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

  //  If we are checking this cell, we do
  [self.checkedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];

  //  If we are unchecking, just enumerate over the items in checkedIndexPaths and remove the one where the row and section match.
}

@end
```

This is all just skeleton code and isn't tested, but hopefully it gives you the jist.

Comment: @mason : Thanks for the reply..and can you pls provide me an example that how can i accomplish it.

Comment: sure, have added a very rough outline to my answer. It's just a sketch of how it might work, but I hope it helps. Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: @mason : Thanks for the reply dude...and when i check the following condition if (path.section == indexPath.section && path.row == indexPath.row) { }  when i scroll the tableview the indexpaths are not same...any idea?

Comment: Do you mean on line 8 of the implementation? If so, what the loop does is iterate over all the items in the checkedIndexPath set to see if we find a match for the index path for the cell we are about to render. If we find a match, we know that this cell was checked at some earlier time, so you should do whatever you need to do to show this to the user (add the tick to the checkbox, for instance). If a match is _not_ found, then you should untick the box. I've added comments to the code to try to help illustrate this. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried your code but when i scroll the uitableview, the follwoing condition never gets called - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Normal layout stuff goes here...

for (NSIndexPath *path in self.checkedIndexPaths)
{
if (path.section == indexPath.section && path.row == indexPath.row)
{
// If we are here, then we should check this cell
}
}
}

Comment: when scroll teh tableview , the indexpath.row shows as 8 instead of 0 ( but the path.row shows as 0).really i saved the path.row value  as 0

Comment: Have you added code to add checked items to the set? Can you post your code somewhere online? That way I could take a look and see exactly what needs to be done.

Comment: @Mason you can use `[set containsObject:]` and `[set removeObject:]` without problems. No need to manually loop over all entries.

Comment: @fluchtpunkt are you sure? Surely [set containsObject:] will compare the pointers, not the values? I.e. it is conceivable (or even likely?) that the same index path (i.e. same row and section) could be represented by 2 objects with different memory addresses, so [set containsObject:] would fail? I realise I could use the [NSIndexPath compare] method rather than comparing row and section manually, but I wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: @Mason : Hi, have added my code into the question.Thanks for your time.

Comment: ok, I had a look and put my thoughts [here](http://www.copypastecode.com/68116/). Let me know if you need more explanation. One thing: your cb variable is odd because it's not declared in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Is it declared in the header? If so, this seems very odd! Note also that I use a tag to fish out the button later in the method. You should probably use a #define in the header file to keep this tidy.

Comment: @Mason : i tried your code also but still when scroll the tableview up and down the checkmark moves to another row as usual.....

Comment: ok, could you put your full project directory somewhere so I can take a look and run it myself? It'll be very hard to debug this over StackOverflow.

Comment: @Mason : Can you pls come for chat in the objective c room

Comment: @mason : i have put my full project directory in the below and thanks for your help http://www.filejumbo.com/Download/AEF06567F1EFB94C

Comment: Hi, the link just times out for me?

Comment: @mason : can you pls come on chat?

Comment: Hi, fixed and upload here: http://www.filejumbo.com/Download/5CD87D16CDF299B5 I've included comments to explain what's going on. I had to change the base SDK to 4.2 as I don't have 4.1 on this machine. If you don't know how to change back to 4.1, just open the files in a different editor and copy and paste the code into your project.

Answer (score 5):

save the checked items in your datasource.

I usually save the `NSIndexPaths` of the selected objects in a `NSMutableSet`.
And in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I check if the indexpath is part of the set with the selected indexpaths.

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableSet *set;
}

// implementation:

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    set = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.row];
    if ([set containsObject:indexPath]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([set containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [set removeObject:indexPath];
    }
    else {
        [set addObject:indexPath];
    }
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```